# Is there a symbol for "multiple"?

Tags: numbers, symbols

Not sure if I should be on another site, possibly Math, but is there a generic symbol *specifically* for "multiple"

For example, I'm trying to breakdown solutions based on number of cases

- 0 Cases -> Do solution 1
- 1 Case -> Do solution 2
- ****"Multiple"**** Cases -> Do solution 3

Was thinking of "X Cases", but that can also be singular

Comment: Maths site for symbols. I don’t answer questions in comments but you might think about the relationship of multiple to 1. I think there is a symbol for that.

Comment: You could use ">1" case which can be pronounced "More than one case"

Comment: I would simply say "2 or more cases".

Comment: ">1" is good, succinct and covers all cases. "2 or more" is accurate but looking for something short, preferably a single character if it exists

Comment: I'm glad that you like my suggestion. It is, of course, related to the form of a programming Case statement which would read something like "Case numOfCases/=0 then Call Sol1/=1 Then Call Sol2/>1Then Call Sol3/Else print "Number of cases cannot be negative"/End Case

Comment: @Boldben If you could add as an answer please I'll mark it as answered

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is looking for a non-English term/symbol.

Comment: @Lawrence I am looking for an English term/symbol, just not sure if one exists

Comment: @Mackija You already found one - "multiple".

Comment: @Lawrence I believe it is implied that I am looking for an alternative, preferably symbolic. If you think I could be more clear, please suggest an edit

Comment: How is a symbolic alternative _English_?

Comment: @Lawrence Again if you think I could be more clear, please suggest an edit

Comment: Sorry, I can't suggest a suitable edit because I don't understand what *English* aspect you're looking for. It looks like you have an English word that you want to replace with something that isn't English. I don't think that's on-topic here - for on-topic questions here, the answer should be something about English. In any case, you've found what you're looking for and we seem to be talking at cross-purposes, so I'll withdraw from this conversation while we're still being civil :) . Enjoy your day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ">1 case" which can be pronounced "More than one case"

This would mean that the breakdown you give would have the form of a programming Case statement which would read something like

> Select Case numOfCases

> Case 0

> Call Sol1

> Case 1

> Call Sol2

> Case >1

> Call Sol3

> Case Else

> print "Number of cases cannot be negative"

> End Case